# BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method save does not exist. Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, save, laravel-5

Hello I am new to laravel and now I am facing this error `BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method save does not exist.`

If I `var_dump(); die();` all of the outputs then I am getting all of them but when I use save method to save the results in to the database it gives me this error of `save method does not exist`. I dont know where in my code am I doing it wrong.

Please see the route controller and view for proper understanding. Thank you in advance.

## Controller

```
public function td($id) {

    $tn = $this->t->getAllTn();
    $to = $this->t->getAllTo();

    $time = Carbon\Carbon::now(); // current time
    $time->toDateTimeString(); // converting time to string

    if((isset($_POST["n"]) && !empty($_POST["n"]))) {
        $tn->t_type_id = Input::get('options');
        $tn->d_id = $id;
        $tn->result = Input::get('message');
        $tn->date = $time;

        // var_dump($tn->date);
        // var_dump($tn->t_type_id);
        // var_dump($tn->d_id);
        // var_dump($tn->result);
        // die();

        Session::flash('message', 'Your tn has been added.');
        $tn->save();

    } else if((isset($_POST["o"]) && !empty($_POST["o"]))) {

        $to->d_id = $id;
        $to->outcome = Input::get('message');
        $to->date = $time->toDateTimeString();

        // var_dump($to->d_id);
        // var_dump($to->outcome);
        // var_dump($to->date = $time->toDateTimeString());
        // die();

        Session::flash('message', 'Your to has been added.');
        $to->save();
    }
    return redirect('/t');
}
```

## Route

```
Route::get('/t/{id}', 'TController@td');
Route::post('/t/{id}', 'TController@td');
```

## View

```
 <div class="form-group">
<form action="/t/{{ $d['id'] }}" method="post">

                    {{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="panel-body"><h4>Heading here</h4></div>
        <select class="form-control" id="options" name="options" style="width:100%" type="checkbox">

            @foreach($t as $t)
                <option value="{{ $t->id }}">{{ $t->type }}</option>
            @endforeach 

        </select>
    </div> 

<div class="col-md-4" id="value" align="center">
            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                Enter text below
                </div>

                        <div class="form-group has-success">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Please enter your message here..." rows="5"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="n" value="A-N">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="o" value="A-O">
                        </div>
                </form>
            <!--          Notes: <br/>-->

        </div>

<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function hide() {
$("#value").hide();
$("#h").hide();
 $("#search").hide();
}

function show() {
$("#value").show();
$("#h").show();
 $("#search").show();
}

function initHandlers() {
$("#options").on('click', function() {
    show();
});
}

hide();
initHandlers();

</script>
```

## Interface Implementation

```
public function getAllTn() {
  return TN::all();
}

public function getAllTO(){
  return TO::all();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to save a collection? `$to` is the result of `TO::all()`, which should return a `Collection`.

Comment: it is just a text area message along with an id and date time `e.g 'This is message" added on user id '5'`... I dont know why am I getting it ...

Comment: I am just trying to store `id` and `result (message)` under their columns in database.

Comment: `TO:all()` means to get all the columns in the `table TO` and if you see `$to->d_id = $id;
        $to->outcome = Input::get('message');
        $to->date = $time->toDateTimeString();` then I am only requesting these columns from the form in the controller and which is input by the user through the form in the view ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of instantiating `Model`s is wrong. Try something like:

```
$to = new TO();

$to->d_id = $id;
$to->outcome = Input::get('message');
$to->date = $time->toDateTimeString();

$to->save();
```

Comment: this will work for sure but if you see in the view there are two buttons `T-A` and `T-O` so what actually I am trying to do is that when user clicks on `T-A` the data saves in `TA` table and when user clicks on `T-O` the data gets stored in the table `TO`. For that I have used `if((isset($_POST["n"]) && !empty($_POST["n"])))` ... Did you get my point ?

Comment: o yes it's done ... thank you so much for the help ... you were right actually I was instantiating the 'model wrong' ... I call ` new TO` in `isset` and it is working ... I forgot this part ... Thank you so much for the help ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to fetch all items to update all items with the same data?

If the model fields are fillable, you can just mass assign them.

```
$data = [
    't_type_id' => request()->input('options'),
    'd_id'      => $id,
    'result'    => request()->input('message'),
    'date'      => $time->toDateTimeString()
];

TN::update($data); // this will update all TN entries
```

Not sure if you just need to update 1 or a lot of items in the TN table?